# Set the progress in Android

Tags: java, android, arduino

I'm making a project - Android - Arduino.

I have a seekbar to handle the temperature, to set it to 20'-35'.

When i open the program i want the seekbar to be set to the temperature that the sensor is set, not to 0 and let me set it.

This is the code for my seekbar:

```
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {

     public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
     {
          tvTemp.setText(Double.toString(progress + 20));
     }
     public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
     public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="35"
        android:progress="20" />
```

**Through xml you can do it as :**
`android:progress="20"` means 20 is default position. Starting point of seek bar.

**Or in your code you can do it like:**

```
your_seekBar.setProgress(start_position);
ie.your_seekBar.setProgress(20);
```

Then you can try :

```
your_seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {               

            int progressChanged = 0;

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
                progressChanged = progress;
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Toast.makeText(your_activity.this,"seek bar progress:"+progressChanged, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: How i can set the default position from the java code? Because i will receive that information from the Arduino

Comment: if you read my post, you will find that. eg. your_seekBar.setProgress(Arduino_value);

Comment: that is Activity context, actually that is an activity in my code. Plz use your activity. I have edited my answer :)

Comment: your_seekBar.setProgress(start_position);
ie.your_seekBar.setProgress(20);

This gives me a lot of errors, tells me that your_seekBar cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Sry with that i'm still learning and i forgot that is my activity :), but the error with setProgress i can't make it :(

Comment: SeekBar your_seekBar= (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);//your_seekBar is just a name I used to explain you that , it is a seekbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in your xml file:

```
android:progress="20"
```

Comment: Yes but how i can add this from the information i receive from the Arduino? because the variable you can change it only in java code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
seekBar.setProgress(value)
```

below

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener
```

If your value is between 20 and 35, you may also want to specify

```
android:max="35"
android:min="20"
```

for your seekbar in your xml layout

Answer (score 0):

SeekBar is inherited from ProgressBar,
So you can use 'setProgress()' method to set progress on startup.

seekBar.setProgress(someValue);

it will work